# Cross Browser Text Stroke & Blur

Tags: jquery, css

So I'm trying to get a photoshop text effect to happen on a webpage.
Basically the text is white, there is a solid black outline and a white blur outside of the stroke as well.

Cross browser hell!

I've been playing with all sorts of text shadow, text-stroke and ms filters but just can't get something that looks consistent across all browsers. Firefox shows the outline but it's grey and can't seem to get a combo of filters to work in IE. Here's one of my efforts:

```
color: #FFF;
-webkit-text-fill-color: white;
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
-webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #ffffff, -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
letter-spacing: -3px;
font-style: italic;
filter: glow(color=black,strength=1);
```

I'm also using an embedded font with @fontface.

Does anyone know of a jquery solution that might allow me to style this text?
I really don't want to have to resort to images as the text styling is used throughout the entire site.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

<----------------EDIT----------------->

Too true I was a little vague. Super late last night and was hoping for a magic jquery solution or something of the like. I have not worked with SVG text as of yet so I'll definitely give that a try this morning as it looks like it'll handle a majority of the popular browsers.

I understand that Photoshop and designing for the web are very different but I am provided PSDs and have to build a site from that to the best of my ability.

I work on a Mac and test IE via Virtual Box. At the moment I'm using IE9 but have a copy of IE10 downloading now for further testing.

This is a jpg example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: This is a jpg example of what I'm trying to achieve]

Comment: You should not expect to reproduce Photoshop effects in web browsers. They are very different programs. Regarding specific effects, you should specify them exactly, with an image (or a link to an image, at a permanent URL) and post a complete testable document showing your best effort so far, describing the results more exactly by browser (e.g., “IE” is a very vague reference – IE 11 Preview, IE 10, IE 9, or something older?).

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested this is going to be difficult; it could well be more trouble than it's worth. Also, JQuery is certainly not the right tool for this job.

As you've found already, the `text-shadow` style will give you the blur behind the text. If the text outline is *really* important to you, I'd use inline SVG for that:

```
<svg>
    <text x="80" y="80" stroke="red" font-size="80px">Hi</text>
</svg>
```

(See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgWYR/). Cross-browser compatibility for inline SVG: [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-html5).)

Unfortunately if you use inline SVG, you can't use CSS's `text-shadow`, so you'll have to create an SVG filter with [`feGaussianBlur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feGaussianBlur).